# only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an int value passed from the first screen to the second screen and I can have my value without any problem...My problem is that I want to add my recieved value to astring to complete and start working with my api which reqires to add the imported value of the first screen...Iam trapped between the recieved int which I can not change it to a static, and the api string which reqires the added value to be a static

the second Screen:

```
   class CatsNews extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    _CatsNewsState createState() => new _CatsNewsState();

    }

    class _CatsNewsState extends State<CatsNews> {
    int _id ;
    String root = "http://api.0mr.net";
    String  url = "/api/GetCategoryById/$_id";
    @override

    List data;

    Future<String> getDrawerItem() async {
    var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    setState(() {
    var respondbody = json.decode(response.body);
    data = respondbody["StoriesCategory"];
    });
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Cat Screen'),
    ),
    body:  Center()
```

I get the value through the shared preferences and it works fine if it was inside Widget build(BuildContext context)

```
   @override
    void initState() {
    getIntPrefrence().then(updatId);
    super.initState();
    this.getDrawerItem();
    }

    void updatId(int id) {
    setState(() {
    this._id = id;
    });
    }
    }
```

UPDATE: 
I have added the Srting url to the initstate() and the code is as foloows:

```
    class _CatsNewsState extends State<CatsNews> {
    @override
    List data;
    int _id  ;
    var response;
    String root = "http://-api.0mr.net";
    String url ;


    Future<String> getDrawerItem() async {
    response = await http
    .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    setState(() {
    var respondbody = json.decode(response.body);
    data = respondbody["StoriesCategory"];
    });
    }

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('$_id'),
    ),
    body: Center()

    }


    Future<int> getIntPrefrence() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int id = pref.getInt("id");
    return id;
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getIntPrefrence().then(updatId);
    updateurl();
    this.getDrawerItem();

    //initResponse();


    }

    updateurl() {
    setState(() {
    this.url= "$root/api/CategoryId/$_id";

    });
    }

    void updatId(int id) {
    setState(() {
    this._id = id;
    });
    }


    }
```

the previous issue was solved by adiing the String to the initstate(), but the updated values does not add to the String and deals witht the imported int id as null or zero,however the int id works fine and shows the imported value in any widget inside the  Widget build(BuildContext context)

Comment: Set the URL in `initState`

Answer (score 1):

The offending code is probably

```
var response = await http.get(...
```

You can't have arbitrary code in a field initializer which is the part after `=` in above code.

Dart has a strict order in object creation steps.
Field initializers are executed before the constructor initialization list and before the constructor initialization list of super classes.

Only after all the constructor initialization lists of all super classes are executed, the constructor bodies are executed and only from then on is it allowed to access `this`, the instance of your class being created.

Your code accesses `this` (implicitly) before that and at this point object initialization isn't done and therefore access to `this` prohibited to prevent undefined bahavior.

Static members are safe to access, because they don't depend on object initialization. They are ready to use without an instance entirely.

What the error message is telling you is that your initializer is trying to do things that are not possible at this point and you need to move the code somewhere else.

The field initialization code can be moved to the constructor initialization list. This is usually done if the field is supposed to be `final`,
or to the constructor body, or to a method - as shown below.

```
var response;
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _initResponse();
}

void _initResponse() async {
  response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    setState(() {
    var respondbody = json.decode(response.body);
    data = respondbody["StoriesCategory"];
  });
}
```

Because `initState` does not allow `async` we move the code to another method (`_initResponse`) that we call from `initState`.

Comment: my problem is not with the response at all and if I put in the String a valid api it works without any issues...my problem is when I try to add the imported value to the exited String as " String  url = "/api/GetCategoryById/$_id" " here the mentioned message appears...I want to be able to add the imported value to the String to start my request..I have added the String to the init state and the message has disappeared now, but the value imported from the first screen does not apply in the String ant the request deal with it as null or zero, when it works fine in any widget inside Widget build

Comment: I don't see that code in your question. It's difficult to know what code exactly causes your error without more specific information. I just made a guess what code could cause the problem.

Comment: String  url = "/api/GetCategoryById/$_id";....the problem in this line as I can not add the value of the id to the String url...it works now after adding the String url to the initState() but only if set a value manually to the int id like int id =5; here it will get the api with the value of 5 and remain like this nevertheless what the imported value from the first screen is..what I should do to solve this issue?...thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the issue is. There are dozens of questions with answers about how to get the value from one file to another or from one class to another. Please try to look them up. Sounds like this is what you want to do.

Comment: after a lot of searching and trying the problem is solved now...I both the changed variable and the shared preferences value in the getDrawerItem() function and it solved the issue...your suggestion helped me so much so thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to hear \o/

Answer (score 0):

the solution of my problem was adding both the imported value and the String which I want to edit according to it inside the method which will start my api request as follows:

```
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getDrawerItem();
    }

    Future<String> getDrawerItem() async {
    int _id ;
    String url;
    SharedPreferences pref = await
    SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _id = (pref.getInt("id")?? 0);
    url = "http://gomhuriaonline-api.0mr."
        "net/api/GetCategoryById/$_id";
    print(url);
    response = await http
    .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: 
    {"Accept": "application/json"});
    setState(() {
    var respondbody = json.decode(response.body);
    data = respondbody["StoriesCategory"];
    });
    }
    }
```